# ionic ios app failed to load resource?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to run the ionic application on ios build is happening successful, also application is running successfully on real iPhone 4s but when I open console using web inspector of safari I am getting following errors :

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server. (ionicons.ttf, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server. (ionicons.woff, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server. (ionicons.svg, line 0)
```

Also app is showing errors in log about failure to load some js files as well.

Because of these & some other resource loading failures my app is not behaving as expected.

The missing files showing in logs at `www/fonts` directory but I see these files in `www\lib\ionic\fonts` directory of project. But I guess run-time it is not able to get these files. Also there is no font directory in my apps `www` directory.

Also these files are not under css directory.

Do I need to install any plugin in iOS for this ? What might go wrong ? my ionic version is 2.1.4 & cordova version is 6.4.0.

Comment: Are these declared in a CSS ?

Comment: @Eric please have look @ edited question